# Master Site links not working under iis6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6

ASP MVC 1.0 being hosted on IIS 6.

I set up the wildcard filtering already.

The path ../../site.css and the like in the master page (shared/site.master) do not work when posted to the IIS 6 staging site. I ended up hard coding them to the site.

Works fine on the ASP .Net VS dev server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Url.Content for this, e.g.:

```
<link href="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/style/Site_Master.css") %>" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
```

The `~` means "the site root", whereever that happens to be.

Comment: Yes this fixed the IIS 6 problems. The only minor issue is I am trying to keep server side mark up out of the layout code, but it seems I am stuck.

Comment: Feel free to ask a new question about this, with examples of what you're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the IIS log file to see if/which request is being made?